# Localization with django and xgettext

Tags: django, django-templates, xgettext

I am working on translation of my site, but when I try to run command:

```
manage.py makemessages --locale=bs
```

I constantly get error like:

```
CommandError: errors happened while running xgettext on rjsmin.py
xgettext: Non-ASCII string at .\compressor\filters\jsmin\rjsmin.py:59.
          Please specify the source encoding through --from-code.
```

What shell I do?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem. At the top of the rjsmin.py, change the "- * - coding: ascii -*-" to "- * - coding: utf-8 - * -"